# How do I fix this ImportError in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, windows, jupyter-notebook, importerror

I need to use pandas for my project and whenever I write:

```
import pandas as pd
```

this error comes up:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'infer_dtype_from_scalar' from partially initialized module 'pandas.core.dtypes.cast' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Soorya Suresh\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py)
```

let me know how I can fix this so I can work with pandas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pip uninstall pandas` and `pip install pandas` then try to import it again.